# How can I add a field to a view description

Tags: views, entities, taxonomy-terms

I'm running into a quite simple problem : I would add fields to a view description, in order to list my views by this field.

Example : add a taxonomy field to the views, let's say "View color". Then, I would create a view of views, only for the views having a color, ordered by their colors and letting me see a XML containing the color and a link to the view's page :

```
<...>
    <view>
        <color>red</color>
        <link>http://example.com/path-to-red-view</link>
        <color>blue</color>
        <link>http://example.com/path-to-blue-view</link>
    <....>
</...>
```

I don't want to generate the links by rewriting (I know how to do that), but really add a field to the views.

The question is a bit wobbly, but I don't figure out how to write it. I found nothing on the web describing what I want to do, maybe due to that.

Thereby, all help is welcome !

Thanks

Comment: Views aren't field-able, I think you'll end up needing to write something custom for this

Comment: Thanks @Clive, you are faster at answering than me at writing ! Is something possible with https://www.drupal.org/project/entity or something ?

Comment: Maybe creating a content type which contains the view name and a taxonomy field, then getting that from the view, linked by its name ?

Comment: Okay, let's say I'm less ambitious : can I create a view listing all my other views, getting their name and path (just to know) ?

Comment: Sure, have a look at how Views does the same thing with the main admin page in the Views UI module

Comment: What a good idea ! So obvious I didn't think about it... I bet I'm tired ;) I'll see that tomorrow. Thanks ! I'll post here whats new.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that it will provide all the functionality you are looking for, but you could look into [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view):

> This module allows you to embed a view as a field in a view. A new
>   field handler is made available, so this can also be used in area
>   (header/footer/empty) handlers as well as rows.
>
> This view handler can accept arguments from fields of the parent view
>   using tokens and pass them into the child view for each row. Raw or
>   rendered token values can be used, as well as static values.

Comment: Sure, I'd looked at this module, but it does not seem to be what I expect : being able to list a group of views filtered by a criterion, preferably a field. Not sure I'm very precise ?